# How can I set the offset of a div element in SF lightning without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

I have a tootip div in my component. I need to change the position of the tooltip according to the hovered element. How can I do it without using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Use the native javascript for that. The following methods are useful while positioning an element:

```
// First get the element
var e = document.getElementById("you-element-id");
```

- e.position
- e.style.top / e.style.bottom
- e.style.left / e.style.right
- e.style.clientX / e.style.clientY

And try to search for some DOM positioning tutorials on the web.